# How to have groupby.first not remove timezone info from datetime columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Observe this strange behavior:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import datetime

In [3]: import pytz

In [4]: dates = [datetime.datetime(2015,1,i,tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')) for i in range(1,5)]

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b']*2,'B': dates})

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   A                          B
0  a  2015-01-01 00:00:00-08:00
1  b  2015-01-02 00:00:00-08:00
2  a  2015-01-03 00:00:00-08:00
3  b  2015-01-04 00:00:00-08:00

In [7]: grouped = df.groupby('A') 

In [8]: grouped.nth(0) #B stays a datetime.datetime with timezone info
Out[8]: 
                           B
A                           
a  2015-01-01 00:00:00-08:00
b  2015-01-02 00:00:00-08:00

In [9]: grouped.head(1) #B stays a datetime.datetime with timezone 
Out[9]: 
                           B
0  2015-01-01 00:00:00-08:00
1  2015-01-02 00:00:00-08:00

In [10]: grouped.first() #B is naive pd.TimeStamp in UTC
Out[10]: 
                    B
A                    
a 2015-01-01 08:00:00
b 2015-01-02 08:00:00
```

Would love to know why this happens, and if there's a way to prevent it. Are there related issues I should be aware of?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me the same thing happens if you do `grouped.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0])`, worth posting as an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: @JohnE  Think you meant this link, right? I'm dealing with timestamps not timedeltas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-zone-handling

Comment: @EdChum that's what I figured, but wanted to ask here first. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: voila: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10668

Comment: Oops, bad copy and paste by me.  Yes, you have the correct link that I had intended to paste.  You might want to post this there also:  `dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01',periods=4,tz='US/Pacific')`  It doesn't help, but it's probably the more canonical pandas way to do it b/c it's using pandas built in time-zone support.  Although I'm not really sure if this makes a difference to the problem (but it does give a time that differs by 7 minute compared to how you did it)